# Query on multiple tables identical tables with different values Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am in need of some help with mysql since I'm a novice with it. I need to count the values of different tables from different databases and put them all in one table, after that make an index for each count, for example:

```
 _______________________
|           |           |
|  Indexes  |   Counts  |
|___________|___________|
|           |           |
|  Index 1  |  Count 1  |
|___________|___________|
|           |           |
|  Index 2  |  Count 2  |
|___________|___________|
|           |           |
|  Index 3  |  Count 3  |
|___________|___________|
|           |           |
|  Index 4  |  Count 4  |
|___________|___________|
```

But like I'm doing it right now (with UNION) it appears like:

```
 ___________
|           |
|  Counts   |
|___________|
|           |
|  Count 1  |
|___________|
|           |
|  Count 2  |
|___________|
|           |
|  Count 3  |
|___________|
|           |
|  Count 4  |
|___________|
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The code I'm currently using is this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "db1" FROM `db1`.`tb1`
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "db2" FROM `db2`.`tb2`
```

Comment: "like I'm doing it right now (with UNION)" - how exactly are you doing it?

Comment: Editted, sorry :p

Comment: What is ```indexes``` here? Column name? or Index?

Comment: It would be a name to organize the counts by the name of the db where they proceed I know it's a mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT "db1.tb1" as "INDEXES", COUNT(*) AS "COUNTS" FROM `db1`.`tb1`
UNION
SELECT "db2.tb2" as "INDEXES", COUNT(*) AS "COUNTS" FROM `db2`.`tb2`
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Been 5 days stuck with that and couldn't find an answer.